# Java and Objective-c program on the same GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm developing an application divided in to parts. Server part is a Objective-c application and the client part is a Java application.
I would like to bring both application in the same GitHub repository. Is that possible ? I would like to avoid creating 2 different repository for the same project.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 3):

Just set the repository root to contain both projects like

```
-Repository
 --Java
 --Objective-C
```

I don't really see a problem there

Comment: Could you tell me a little bit more about how to do it ? I'm using Eclipse and Xcode. So how can I push commits from both SDK directly in dedicated sub-directory ?

Comment: For achieving what you desire I wouldn't push commits from Eclipse and XCode. Actually I'm working in a repository like I mentioned and I make my commits directly from console.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible -- Git is pretty ignorant of the *types* of content you have, and is just concerned with the content it is storing. Honestly, though, if unless the projects are really closely related (i.e., the Objective-C program actually needs the Java program to do work, or vice-versa) I'd keep the code in separate repositories -- your development histories will be much more organized that way.